# Appfog + Rails 3 + Postgresql + IronWorker => could not connect to server: Connection timed out (PG::Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, appfog, ironworker

I have a Rails 3 app deployed on Appfog with a postgresql database. I would like to run background jobs with IronWorker but i can not connect to my database.

Here are my ironworker files (.worker + my_worker.rb)

.worker

```
runtime "ruby"
gemfile '../Gemfile'
dir "../app/models" # merge all models
full_remote_build true
exec "my_worker.rb"
```

my_worker.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
require 'pg'
require 'models/my_model.rb'


def setup_database
  puts "Database connection details:#{params['database'].inspect}"
  return unless params['database']
  # estabilsh database connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(params['database'])
end


setup_database
@my_models = My_model.all
```

Then i create a task, with passing the database connection to ironworker:

```
client = IronWorkerNG::Client.new
client.tasks.create("my_worker", database:Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env])
```

And here is the error i have in IronWorker

```
/task/__gems__/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection timed out (PG::Error)
Is the server running on host "10.0.48.220" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Can somebody help me out to connect my Appfog DB from IronWorker ?

Thanks a lot in advance

--
Mathieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, AppFog blocking external connections to their databases
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/appfog-users/I31ni0pff9I

Possible solutions:

- Poke AppFog
- Switch to other database hoster
- Make some kind of tunnel.
  As example, IronWorker platform allows you to interact with any non-privileged code during worker's execution, so you can try to set up SSH tunnel to 'good' machine.